# Blurred background in list sencha touch

Tags: background, sencha-touch-2, css-filters

I have a list which contains main menu of my mobile app and is visible when user swipes to right or clicks on menu icon. I want to have the background of this list and hence main menu to be blurred.

I checked out the **css filter:blur** property and it can be done using that but you need to have an extra div under the div which has your content and apply filter:blur to it as shown in this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/aniketpant/pen/DsEve)

Below is my list code for sencha touch

```
Ext.define('MobileApp.view.SlideList', {
   extend: 'Ext.List',
   xtype: 'slidelist',

   config: {
      cls: 'slide1',
      variableHeights: true,
      onItemDisclosure: true,
      store: 'SlideListStore',


      itemTpl: ['<div class="slideImg" style="background-image:url(resources/images/{img});"></div>',
          '{title}',
      '<div class="settingImg" id="settingImg" style="background-image:url(resources/icons/nw-icons/settings.png);"></div>'].join(''),

      listeners: {
         initialize: function (comp, eOpts) {
            comp.element.on(
               'swipe',
               function (event, node, options, eOpts)
               {
                  /*send event as a argument to get direction of swipe*/
                  this.fireEvent('swipe', event);
               },
               comp
            );
         }
      }
   }
});
```

I cant figure out where to place the extra div and apply **filter:blur** to it. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to achieve https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4tb

Here is how you can accomplish this

1. Add an empty div as html property of the list
2. remove the background of the list
3. add css to blur the image

   > .setMyBackground {
   >            position: fixed;
   >           left: 0;
   >        right: 0;
   >              display: block;
   >              background-image: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG');
   >              width:100%;
   >              height: 100%;
   >              -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
   >              -moz-filter: blur(5px);
   >              -o-filter: blur(5px);
   >              -ms-filter: blur(5px);
   >              filter: blur(5px);
   >              z-index:-1;
   >   }
   >
   > .slide1{   background:none;}

Comment: You are the man...thanks a ton...i don't remember how did i miss out on that html config property....that was easy..thank you @Abhi :)